# Android: How to obtain data/anr/traces.txt from Samsung Galaxy Tab?

Tags: android

My application gives an anr while debugging on my Samsung Galaxy Tab.  The device is viewable in DDMS in Eclipse, and I can browse the sdcard with the DDMS file explorer.  But I cannot browse into the data directory (when I click the drop down arrow next to this directory, it appears the directory is open).  Any tips how I can obtain the file?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can fetch the file using the following command:

> adb pull /data/anr/traces.txt

Hope this helps,
Francisco.

Comment: I get "permission denied" when I do this on a Samsung Note II, but the following works:

adb shell "cd /data/anr && cat traces.txt"

Comment: go to adb shell and try to do that from there

Answer (score 30):

for Android Pie+

```
adb bugreport ./bugreport.zip
```

and you will get then in zip file

```
bugreport/FS/data/anr/*
bugreport/FS/data/tombstones/*
```

Answer (score 1):

On some devices the traces file is called `traces.txt.bugreport` for whatever reason. See the other answers for pulling the file to your device.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command. it is hassle free. 
`adb shell "cat /data/anr/traces.txt" | less`