# Android: application dies unexpectedly, leaving me clueless to the reason

Tags: android, crash

My application dies unexpectedly, with no obvious exception.  The crash happens consistently on both my Samsung Galaxy Tab and my emulator; though the logcat output varies depending on the device.  I suspect it has something to do with garbage collection, but cannot glean anything from the logcat.  Any ideas?

Logcat output from death on 2.2 emulator:

```
03-16 15:17:44.104: INFO/DEBUG(31): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-16 15:17:44.104: INFO/DEBUG(31): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic/:2.2/FRF91/43546:eng/test-keys'
03-16 15:17:44.104: INFO/DEBUG(31): pid: 283, tid: 283  >>> com.myapp<<<
03-16 15:17:44.114: INFO/DEBUG(31): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr deadbaad
03-16 15:17:44.114: INFO/DEBUG(31):  r0 00000000  r1 0000000c  r2 00000027  r3 00000000
03-16 15:17:44.114: INFO/DEBUG(31):  r4 00000000  r5 deadbaad  r6 00001728  r7 fdff3fdc
03-16 15:17:44.124: INFO/DEBUG(31):  r8 be965788  r9 00000000  10 be964fc8  fp 00000002
03-16 15:17:44.124: INFO/DEBUG(31):  ip ffffffff  sp be964dd8  lr afd154c5  pc afd11dc4  cpsr 40000030
03-16 15:17:44.544: INFO/DEBUG(31):          #00  pc 00011dc4  /system/lib/libc.so
03-16 15:17:44.544: INFO/DEBUG(31):          #01  pc 0000c678  /system/lib/libc.so
03-16 15:17:44.554: INFO/DEBUG(31): code around pc:
03-16 15:17:44.554: INFO/DEBUG(31): afd11da4 1c2bd00b 2d00682d e026d1fb 2b0068db 
03-16 15:17:44.554: INFO/DEBUG(31): afd11db4 4e17d003 51a02001 4d164798 24002227 
03-16 15:17:44.554: INFO/DEBUG(31): afd11dc4 f7fb702a 2106ee14 ef10f7fc 05592380 
03-16 15:17:44.564: INFO/DEBUG(31): afd11dd4 6091aa01 1c116054 94012006 eab6f7fc 
03-16 15:17:44.564: INFO/DEBUG(31): afd11de4 2200a905 f7fc2002 f7fbeac2 2106ee00 
03-16 15:17:44.564: INFO/DEBUG(31): code around lr:
03-16 15:17:44.564: INFO/DEBUG(31): afd154a4 b0834a0d 589c447b 26009001 686768a5 
03-16 15:17:44.574: INFO/DEBUG(31): afd154b4 220ce008 2b005eab 1c28d003 47889901 
03-16 15:17:44.574: INFO/DEBUG(31): afd154c4 35544306 d5f43f01 2c006824 b003d1ee 
03-16 15:17:44.574: INFO/DEBUG(31): afd154d4 bdf01c30 0002ae7c 000000d4 1c0fb5f0 
03-16 15:17:44.574: INFO/DEBUG(31): afd154e4 43551c3d a904b087 1c16ac01 604d9004 
03-16 15:17:44.574: INFO/DEBUG(31): stack:
03-16 15:17:44.584: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964d98  00000015  
03-16 15:17:44.584: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964d9c  afd1453b  /system/lib/libc.so
03-16 15:17:44.584: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964da0  afd405a0  /system/lib/libc.so
03-16 15:17:44.584: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964da4  afd4054c  /system/lib/libc.so
03-16 15:17:44.584: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964da8  00000000  
03-16 15:17:44.584: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964dac  afd154c5  /system/lib/libc.so
03-16 15:17:44.584: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964db0  00000000  
03-16 15:17:44.584: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964db4  afd1450d  /system/lib/libc.so
03-16 15:17:44.584: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964db8  00000000  
03-16 15:17:44.584: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964dbc  afd40328  /system/lib/libc.so
03-16 15:17:44.594: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964dc0  00000000  
03-16 15:17:44.594: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964dc4  00001728  
03-16 15:17:44.594: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964dc8  fdff3fdc  
03-16 15:17:44.594: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964dcc  afd147ab  /system/lib/libc.so
03-16 15:17:44.594: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964dd0  df002777  
03-16 15:17:44.594: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964dd4  e3a070ad  
03-16 15:17:44.594: INFO/DEBUG(31): #00 be964dd8  00321c38  [heap]
03-16 15:17:44.594: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964ddc  c0000000  
03-16 15:17:44.594: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964de0  afd418dc  /system/lib/libc.so
03-16 15:17:44.604: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964de4  afd10510  /system/lib/libc.so
03-16 15:17:44.604: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964de8  00000003  
03-16 15:17:44.604: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964dec  fffffbdf  
03-16 15:17:44.604: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964df0  00000001  
03-16 15:17:44.604: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964df4  afd40328  /system/lib/libc.so
03-16 15:17:44.604: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964df8  0028e2cf  [heap]
03-16 15:17:44.614: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964dfc  afd0c67d  /system/lib/libc.so
03-16 15:17:44.614: INFO/DEBUG(31): #01 be964e00  00000001  
03-16 15:17:44.614: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964e04  afd0c67d  /system/lib/libc.so
03-16 15:17:44.614: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964e08  00000000  
03-16 15:17:44.614: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964e0c  0000400c  
03-16 15:17:44.614: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964e10  00000002  
03-16 15:17:44.614: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964e14  be965018  [stack]
03-16 15:17:44.614: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964e18  be965038  [stack]
03-16 15:17:44.614: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964e1c  afd0cd65  /system/lib/libc.so
03-16 15:17:44.614: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964e20  0000400c  
03-16 15:17:44.614: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964e24  00000018  
03-16 15:17:44.614: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964e28  00321c60  [heap]
03-16 15:17:44.614: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964e2c  00000000  
03-16 15:17:44.614: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964e30  00000006  
03-16 15:17:44.625: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964e34  afd0cb11  /system/lib/libc.so
03-16 15:17:44.625: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964e38  00000018  
03-16 15:17:44.625: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964e3c  afd0cdb9  /system/lib/libc.so
03-16 15:17:44.634: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964e40  00000018  
03-16 15:17:44.634: INFO/DEBUG(31):     be964e44  ab12dedc  /system/lib/libskia.so
03-16 15:17:45.494: DEBUG/Zygote(33): Process 283 terminated by signal (11)
03-16 15:17:45.505: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Process com.myapp(pid 283) has died.
03-16 15:17:45.505: INFO/WindowManager(59): WIN DEATH: Window{43f7fa48 com.myapp/com.myactivitypaused=false}
03-16 15:17:45.604: INFO/UsageStats(59): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in com.myapp
03-16 15:17:45.614: INFO/BootReceiver(59): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_03 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
03-16 15:17:45.805: DEBUG/dalvikvm(59): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5311 objects / 342504 bytes in 149ms
03-16 15:17:45.824: WARN/InputManagerService(59): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 283 uid 10032
03-16 15:17:46.154: DEBUG/dalvikvm(59): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 442 objects / 65640 bytes in 264ms
03-16 15:17:46.154: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(59): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.756MB for 87768-byte allocation
03-16 15:17:46.314: DEBUG/dalvikvm(59): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 400 objects / 18472 bytes in 155ms
03-16 15:17:46.474: DEBUG/dalvikvm(59): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 414 objects / 144264 bytes in 140ms
```

Logcat output from death on Samsung Galaxy Tab:

```
01-02 16:30:30.608: INFO/DEBUG(2360): Build fingerprint: 'verizon/SCH-I800/SCH-I800/SCH-I800:2.2/FROYO/DJ11:user/release-keys'
01-02 16:30:30.608: INFO/DEBUG(2360): pid: 14201, tid: 14202  >>> com.myapp<<<
01-02 16:30:30.608: INFO/DEBUG(2360): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 000035cd
01-02 16:30:30.608: INFO/DEBUG(2360):  r0 00000010  r1 0e000006  r2 000035c1  r3 3f800000
01-02 16:30:30.608: INFO/DEBUG(2360):  r4 afd42328  r5 002b80c8  r6 0037ae40  r7 0037ae50
01-02 16:30:30.608: INFO/DEBUG(2360):  r8 100ffad0  r9 43062fa0  10 43062f8c  fp 100ffe30
01-02 16:30:30.608: INFO/DEBUG(2360):  ip 00000000  sp 100ffa30  lr afd1067c  pc afd0bd5e  cpsr 80000030
01-02 16:30:30.608: INFO/DEBUG(2360):  d0  643a64696f72646e  d1  6472656767756265
01-02 16:30:30.612: INFO/DEBUG(2360):  d2  0069007400630063  d3  007900740069006c
01-02 16:30:30.612: INFO/DEBUG(2360):  d4  00300031002c0036  d5  0033002c00350031
01-02 16:30:30.612: INFO/DEBUG(2360):  d6  002c003200300030  d7  0031003000300033
01-02 16:30:30.612: INFO/DEBUG(2360):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
01-02 16:30:30.612: INFO/DEBUG(2360):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
01-02 16:30:30.612: INFO/DEBUG(2360):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
01-02 16:30:30.612: INFO/DEBUG(2360):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
01-02 16:30:30.612: INFO/DEBUG(2360):  d16 0000000000e67207  d17 3fe999999999999a
01-02 16:30:30.612: INFO/DEBUG(2360):  d18 3fe0000000000000  d19 3fe00000000000b4
01-02 16:30:30.612: INFO/DEBUG(2360):  d20 4008000000000000  d21 3fd99a27ad32ddf5
01-02 16:30:30.612: INFO/DEBUG(2360):  d22 3fd24998d6307188  d23 3fcc7288e957b53b
01-02 16:30:30.612: INFO/DEBUG(2360):  d24 3fc74721cad6b0ed  d25 3fc39a09d078c69f
01-02 16:30:30.612: INFO/DEBUG(2360):  d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
01-02 16:30:30.612: INFO/DEBUG(2360):  d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
01-02 16:30:30.612: INFO/DEBUG(2360):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
01-02 16:30:30.612: INFO/DEBUG(2360):  scr 80000012
01-02 16:30:30.643: INFO/DEBUG(2360):          #00  pc 0000bd5e  /system/lib/libc.so
01-02 16:30:30.643: INFO/DEBUG(2360):          #01  pc 0000d00a  /system/lib/libc.so
01-02 16:30:30.643: INFO/DEBUG(2360):          #02  pc 0002d0ec  /system/lib/libskia.so
01-02 16:30:30.647: INFO/DEBUG(2360):          #03  pc 0007b9d8  /system/lib/libskia.so
01-02 16:30:30.647: INFO/DEBUG(2360):          #04  pc 0007fbec  /system/lib/libskia.so
01-02 16:30:30.647: INFO/DEBUG(2360):          #05  pc 0007fc38  /system/lib/libskia.so
01-02 16:30:30.647: INFO/DEBUG(2360):          #06  pc 00084184  /system/lib/libskia.so
01-02 16:30:30.647: INFO/DEBUG(2360):          #07  pc 000841a0  /system/lib/libskia.so
01-02 16:30:30.647: INFO/DEBUG(2360):          #08  pc 000816a0  /system/lib/libskia.so
01-02 16:30:30.647: INFO/DEBUG(2360):          #09  pc 000816e8  /system/lib/libskia.so
01-02 16:30:30.651: INFO/DEBUG(2360):          #10  pc 000557ba  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
01-02 16:30:30.651: INFO/DEBUG(2360):          #11  pc 00016df4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-02 16:30:30.651: INFO/DEBUG(2360):          #12  pc 00045244  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-02 16:30:30.651: INFO/DEBUG(2360):          #13  pc 0001bd58  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-02 16:30:30.651: INFO/DEBUG(2360):          #14  pc 00022754  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-02 16:30:30.655: INFO/DEBUG(2360):          #15  pc 000215f4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-02 16:30:30.655: INFO/DEBUG(2360):          #16  pc 0005c584  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-02 16:30:30.655: INFO/DEBUG(2360):          #17  pc 0005c7b4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-02 16:30:30.655: INFO/DEBUG(2360):          #18  pc 00051ff6  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-02 16:30:30.655: INFO/DEBUG(2360):          #19  pc 00052082  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-02 16:30:30.655: INFO/DEBUG(2360):          #20  pc 00052558  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-02 16:30:30.659: INFO/DEBUG(2360):          #21  pc 0004f9a8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-02 16:30:30.659: INFO/DEBUG(2360):          #22  pc 000111b0  /system/lib/libc.so
01-02 16:30:30.659: INFO/DEBUG(2360):          #23  pc 00010ca0  /system/lib/libc.so
01-02 16:30:30.659: INFO/DEBUG(2360): code around pc:
01-02 16:30:30.659: INFO/DEBUG(2360): afd0bd3c 8084f0c0 d004428d 18e04ba2 428d6901 
01-02 16:30:30.659: INFO/DEBUG(2360): afd0bd4c 60d5d37c e07b60aa 69bb68fd d01642bd 
01-02 16:30:30.659: INFO/DEBUG(2360): afd0bd5c f8d268ba 45bcc00c 68a9d102 d00542b9 
01-02 16:30:30.659: INFO/DEBUG(2360): afd0bd6c 93029201 ff66f7fe 9a019b02 18214895 
01-02 16:30:30.659: INFO/DEBUG(2360): afd0bd7c 42826908 60d5bf24 d22060aa 697de01b 
01-02 16:30:30.659: INFO/DEBUG(2360): code around lr:
01-02 16:30:30.663: INFO/DEBUG(2360): afd1065c e2166903 1a000018 e5940000 e1a02004 
01-02 16:30:30.663: INFO/DEBUG(2360): afd1066c e2006a02 e1a00006 e3861001 ebfff9e1 
01-02 16:30:30.663: INFO/DEBUG(2360): afd1067c e3500000 0a00000e e3560000 e3865002 
01-02 16:30:30.663: INFO/DEBUG(2360): afd1068c 03a07080 13a07000 ea000000 ebfff9fb 
01-02 16:30:30.663: INFO/DEBUG(2360): afd1069c e1a01004 e1a00005 ebfff9e2 e1a01007 
01-02 16:30:30.663: INFO/DEBUG(2360): stack:
01-02 16:30:30.663: INFO/DEBUG(2360):     100ff9f0  00000000  
01-02 16:30:30.663: INFO/DEBUG(2360):     100ff9f4  afd10560  /system/lib/libc.so
01-02 16:30:30.663: INFO/DEBUG(2360):     100ff9f8  00000000  
01-02 16:30:30.663: INFO/DEBUG(2360):     100ff9fc  afd10560  /system/lib/libc.so
01-02 16:30:30.663: INFO/DEBUG(2360):     100ffa00  afd4372c  /system/lib/libc.so
01-02 16:30:30.663: INFO/DEBUG(2360):     100ffa04  8e6eeccb  
01-02 16:30:30.663: INFO/DEBUG(2360):     100ffa08  afd438e4  /system/lib/libc.so
01-02 16:30:30.663: INFO/DEBUG(2360):     100ffa0c  afd1067c  /system/lib/libc.so
01-02 16:30:30.663: INFO/DEBUG(2360):     100ffa10  afd42328  /system/lib/libc.so
01-02 16:30:30.663: INFO/DEBUG(2360):     100ffa14  0039e58c  [heap]
01-02 16:30:30.663: INFO/DEBUG(2360):     100ffa18  00367430  [heap]
01-02 16:30:30.666: INFO/DEBUG(2360):     100ffa1c  ab213478  /system/lib/libskia.so
01-02 16:30:30.666: INFO/DEBUG(2360):     100ffa20  100ffad0  
01-02 16:30:30.666: INFO/DEBUG(2360):     100ffa24  43062fa0  
01-02 16:30:30.666: INFO/DEBUG(2360):     100ffa28  df002777  
01-02 16:30:30.666: INFO/DEBUG(2360):     100ffa2c  e3a070ad  
01-02 16:30:30.666: INFO/DEBUG(2360): #00 100ffa30  00000000  
01-02 16:30:30.666: INFO/DEBUG(2360):     100ffa34  afd43808  /system/lib/libc.so
01-02 16:30:30.666: INFO/DEBUG(2360):     100ffa38  0037ae48  [heap]
01-02 16:30:30.666: INFO/DEBUG(2360):     100ffa3c  70000040  
01-02 16:30:30.666: INFO/DEBUG(2360):     100ffa40  00263c20  [heap]
01-02 16:30:30.666: INFO/DEBUG(2360):     100ffa44  0037ae48  [heap]
01-02 16:30:30.666: INFO/DEBUG(2360):     100ffa48  0039e58c  [heap]
01-02 16:30:30.666: INFO/DEBUG(2360):     100ffa4c  00367430  [heap]
01-02 16:30:30.666: INFO/DEBUG(2360):     100ffa50  ab213478  /system/lib/libskia.so
01-02 16:30:30.666: INFO/DEBUG(2360):     100ffa54  afd0d00d  /system/lib/libc.so
01-02 16:30:30.666: INFO/DEBUG(2360): #01 100ffa58  0037ae48  [heap]
01-02 16:30:30.666: INFO/DEBUG(2360):     100ffa5c  ab12d0f0  /system/lib/libskia.so
01-02 16:30:31.256: INFO/DEBUG(2360): dumpmesg > /data/log/dumpstate_app_native.log
01-02 16:30:31.280: INFO/BootReceiver(2472): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_07 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
01-02 16:30:31.315: INFO/dumpstate(14256): begin
01-02 16:30:31.346: INFO/dalvikvm(2472): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-02 16:30:31.377: INFO/dalvikvm(2472): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-02 16:30:31.550: INFO/dalvikvm(2556): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-02 16:30:31.553: INFO/dalvikvm(2556): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-02 16:30:31.623: INFO/dalvikvm(2560): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-02 16:30:31.643: INFO/dalvikvm(2563): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-02 16:30:31.655: INFO/dalvikvm(2560): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-02 16:30:31.655: INFO/dalvikvm(2563): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-02 16:30:31.678: INFO/dalvikvm(2566): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-02 16:30:31.682: INFO/dalvikvm(2567): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-02 16:30:31.686: INFO/dalvikvm(2567): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-02 16:30:31.690: INFO/dalvikvm(2623): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-02 16:30:31.702: INFO/dalvikvm(2566): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-02 16:30:31.709: INFO/dalvikvm(2759): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-02 16:30:31.713: INFO/dalvikvm(2759): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-02 16:30:31.713: INFO/dalvikvm(2623): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-02 16:30:31.717: INFO/dalvikvm(2870): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-02 16:30:31.725: INFO/dalvikvm(2870): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-02 16:30:31.737: INFO/dalvikvm(2956): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-02 16:30:31.741: INFO/dalvikvm(3152): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-02 16:30:31.745: INFO/dalvikvm(3152): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-02 16:30:31.745: ERROR/dalvikvm(2956): Failed to write stack traces to /data/anr/traces.txt (1832 of 3200): No such file or directory
01-02 16:30:31.748: INFO/dalvikvm(8461): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-02 16:30:31.748: INFO/dalvikvm(8461): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-02 16:30:31.752: INFO/dalvikvm(8467): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-02 16:30:31.756: INFO/dalvikvm(8477): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-02 16:30:31.760: INFO/dalvikvm(8477): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-02 16:30:31.760: INFO/dalvikvm(8467): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-02 16:30:31.764: INFO/dalvikvm(8483): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-02 16:30:31.768: INFO/dalvikvm(8483): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-02 16:30:31.780: INFO/dalvikvm(8489): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-02 16:30:31.780: INFO/dalvikvm(12905): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-02 16:30:31.780: INFO/dalvikvm(12905): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-02 16:30:31.780: ERROR/dalvikvm(8489): Failed to write stack traces to /data/anr/traces.txt (2005 of 2077): No such file or directory
01-02 16:30:31.784: INFO/dalvikvm(13675): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-02 16:30:31.788: INFO/dalvikvm(13830): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-02 16:30:31.788: INFO/dalvikvm(13830): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-02 16:30:31.788: ERROR/dalvikvm(13675): Failed to write stack traces to /data/anr/traces.txt (1556 of 3611): No such file or directory
01-02 16:30:31.799: INFO/dalvikvm(13870): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-02 16:30:31.799: INFO/dalvikvm(13870): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-02 16:30:31.803: INFO/dalvikvm(13936): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-02 16:30:31.803: INFO/dalvikvm(13944): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-02 16:30:31.807: INFO/dalvikvm(13936): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-02 16:30:31.807: INFO/dalvikvm(13944): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: Extract and paste the `/data/anr/traces.txt` file. Logcat says nothing in this kind of situations.

Comment: Is your app contains some native code ? If yes, then please add that code or check if you accessing any variable which is not allocated yet.

Comment: @Robby Pond. Unfortunately the app is pretty complex, and I have no idea what causes this, so not sure where to start posting sample code.

Comment: @Christian. Weirdly, it only mentions writing to the traces.txt file when executed on the Tablet, which I can not figure out how to retrieve the file off of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316322/android-how-to-obtain-data-anr-traces-txt-from-samsung-galaxy-tab

Comment: @Karan. No, it contains no native code.  Is it possible that due to some garbage collection funkyness, java ends up trying to access an unallocated variable?

Comment: @ab11 It can't be the garbage collection problem, because the error is thrown in native code. Btw you should see some error before this trace in logcat. If you have logs, please add some log statements present above this trace.

Comment: This is a segfault, meaning you, at some point, attempt to access memory you shouldn't be accessing.  I don't think this can happen easily unless native code is somehow involved. I think log statements inserted into your code are going to be your best bet for addressing this.  Another option would be to examine any third-party libraries you're using

Answer (score 2):

You could set a UncaughtExceptionHandler via

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()
```

and try to investigate further with stacktraces etc...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using bugsense?

I found this very useful for trouble shooting application errors when running on devices.