# How to check if the app has crashed/stop working using adb shell?

Tags: android, adb

I'm currently doing this:

-d: call logcat only once and return

```
adb shell logcat -d
```

Then I do a regex search in the log for `Caused by.*"apk name"`.

The problem is, sometimes it does generate this message in the log but the app is still responsive/working.
Would like to ask if there's any better way to check if an app stop working, using adb shell commands.

By stop working I mean, it still open but doesn't responds to anything.

**Note**: I'm not looking for what caused the app to crash, just if it has stopped working.

Answer (score 4):

Did you know that:

> Android stores trace information when it experiences an App is Not Responding (ANR).

You can get more information here: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr#diagnosing_anrs

With this information, I was able to determine if the app is in ANR state via the following commands:

First, get the PID of your app:

```
adb shell ps | grep <app.package.name>
```

The value in second column is the PID. Then, enable root access:

```
adb root
```

Finally, check the /data/anr/:

```
adb shell grep <PID> /data/anr/*<app.package.name>*
```

Note that the asterisks (*) in the last command are important. If you see something like below, your app is in ANR state.

```
/data/anr/traces_app.package.name.txt:----- pid 11828 at 2021-09-06 03:00:05 -----
/data/anr/traces_app.package.name.txt:  | sysTid=11828 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f5cbec
/data/anr/traces_app.package.name.txt:----- end 11828 -----
```

Comment: Could you please, share the commands in windows? I have literally no experience with Linux commands.

Comment: Which command/s? If you are referring to the grep command, you can do so: `adb shell`, then `ps | grep <app.package.name>`.

Comment: When i call  `adb shell ps | grep app.name` it returns 3 lines of values, which one i should use? https://i.imgur.com/ZAus9XU.png also i checked the folder `/data/anr/` and there's only one file which name `traces.txt`.

Comment: Try the pid 3483.

Comment: Only one traces.txt? I think you have an old android device. Try issuing the command `adb shell grep 3483 /data/anr/traces.txt and see what you get.

Comment: `1|dream2lte:/ $ grep 3483 /data/anr/traces.txt
  | state=S schedstat=( 93483139 314162796 1149 ) utm=0 stm=9 core=1 HZ=100`

Comment: Hmmm its not what we are looking for. can you try `grep <package.name> /data/anr/traces.txt`?

Comment: does it need to be included the < > ? returned blank

Comment: No. Use your own package name. grep com.com2us.smon.normal.freefull.google.kr.android.common /data/anr/traces.txt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236943/discussion-between-cesar-and-user1506104).

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```
adb shell pid of the app
```

It returns the PID if such process was found or an empty string otherwise.

for pid u can use adn shell ps

Comment: I'm waiting the app crash again then I can test your answer, but in case the app is still open but irresponsible, the PID will be return empty? or it would help only to know if the app is not running anymore?

Comment: if the app  has not being terminated completely it might show in the pid though the app is in hang state

Answer (score 0):

like user1506104 suggests: looking for the deovr player on my oculus quest 2:

```
... MINGW64 /e/pt
$ ./adb shell ps | grep com.deovr.gearvr
u0_a90 3936 695 3212880 614872 0 0 S com.deovr.gearvr

$ ./adb shell ps -p 3936
USER      PID  PPID     VSZ RSS WCHAN      ADDR S NAME        
u0_a90    3936  695 3212880 616096 0       0 S com.deovr.gearvr
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use also command for directly knowing what is happening with error stack and you will be also able to reach any of crashes:

```
adb logcat *:E
```

Here you can get also more options:
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat#options

Getting actual ANR stack - check this thread how to obtain it from shell:
[Android: How to obtain data/anr/traces.txt from Samsung Galaxy Tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316322/android-how-to-obtain-data-anr-traces-txt-from-samsung-galaxy-tab/58128529)